# Mensagem de "Child vazio" em um Expandable ListView no Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

Desejo criar uma indicação ao usuário informando que um Group de um Expansible ListView não contém nenhum Child (Que o group está vazio) conforme na imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pesquisando pela net, observei alguns métodos, mas achei muito confuso por está em outro idioma. Eu estou tentando isso no código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo. Pois quando o grupo está vazio, meu expandable listview não infla o layout personalizado.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private List<Construtor_Perfil_Usuario> modelList;
    private HashMap<Construtor_Perfil_Usuario,List<Construtor_Medicamentos>> listHashMap;
    private Context context;

    ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<Construtor_Perfil_Usuario> modelList, HashMap<Construtor_Perfil_Usuario, List<Construtor_Medicamentos>> listHashMap) {

        this.modelList = modelList;
        this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return modelList.size();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(i))).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return modelList.get(i);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {

        return Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(i))).get(i1);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    List<String> getValues(int groupPosition, int childPosition){

        List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        listStrings.add(modelList.get(groupPosition).getNomeUsuario());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getNome());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getTipo());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getStatus());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getDosagem());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getEstoque());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getUso());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getDataInicial());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getDataFinal());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getHoraInicial());
        listStrings.add(Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getHoraIntervalo());

        return listStrings;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        String string = modelList.get(groupPosition).getNomeUsuario();

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.expansive_listview_group,null); }


        TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        textView.setText(string);

        TextView textName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewInfoSex);
        if (modelList.get(groupPosition).getSexoUsuario().contains("Feminino")){
            textName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_oval_pink);
        }else{
            textName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_oval_blue);
        }

        String subString = string.substring(0, 1);
        textName.setText(subString);

        return convertView;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) != 0) {

            String nomeMedicamento = Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getNome();
            String statusMedicamento = Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getStatus();
            String estoqueMedicamento = Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getEstoque();
            String dosagemMedicamento = Objects.requireNonNull(listHashMap.get(modelList.get(groupPosition))).get(childPosition).getDosagem();


            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.expansive_listview_child, null);

            }

            TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
            textView.setText(nomeMedicamento);

            ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status_medicamento);

            if (statusMedicamento.equals("ATIVO")) {
                float result = Float.parseFloat(estoqueMedicamento) / Float.parseFloat(dosagemMedicamento);
                if (result <= 3 && result > 1) {
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_atencion_yellow);
                } else if (result <= 1 && result >= 0) {
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_atencion_red);
                } else {
                    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on);
                }
            } else if (statusMedicamento.equals("DESATIVADO")) {
                imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_off);
            }

        }else{

            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.expansive_listview_childempty, null);

            }

        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }


}
```

eu não entendo o que estou fazendo de errado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo no seu código esta quase pronto.
Veja, o método que cria os elementos chield é o `getChildView`, e nele você já verifica se o chield é diferente de zero (se não é vazio):

```
if (getChildrenCount(groupPosition) != 0) ...
```

Você até já tem o `else` para tratar quando não tiver chield, mas você parou por aí, só colocou o código para tratar quando a convertView for null (o que nesse caso não é, somente o chield que é vazio):

```
}else{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.expansive_listview_childempty, null);
    }
}
```

Então o que pode ser feito é dentro deste `else` criar um chield com a mensagem "Chield Vazio" conforme você precisar, por exemplo, o código abaixo ficaria dentro do`else` que esta no seu método `getChieldView`:

```
}else{
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = Objects.requireNonNull(inflater).inflate(R.layout.expansive_listview_childempty, null);
    }

    TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    textView.setText("Chield Vazio");
    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_status_medicamento);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_alarm_off);
}
```

**Editado**
No teste que criei verifiquei que o app quebrava ao clicar em um group que não tinha child, e o problema não era no método `getChildView` mas sim no `getChildrenCount`. Este método retorna a quantidade de filhos que aquele grupo tem, se você passa um grupo que não tem filhos, ele não retorna 0, da erro, pois é a mesma coisa que pegar a posição maior que um vetor.
Segue abaixo o código de exemplo:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ExpandableListViewAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    String groupNames[] = {"Aluno1","Aluno2","Aluno3"};

    String[][] chieldNames= {{"Chield do Aluno1"},{"Chiel do aluno2"}};

    Context context;

    public ExpandableListViewAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        if(i>chieldNames.length-1){
            //Se o group não tiver filho, retorne 1,
            // se retornar 0 o grupo vai aparecer mas não vai expandir
            return 1;
        }
        return chieldNames[i].length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int i) {
        return groupNames[i];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {

        return chieldNames[1][i1];
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return i1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        TextView txtv = new TextView(context);
        txtv.setText(groupNames[i]);
        txtv.setPadding(100,0,0,0);
        txtv.setTextSize(50);
        return txtv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        TextView txtv = new TextView(context);

        //Repare que aqui, para pegar se o grupo não tem filho, não utilizei o método
        // getChildrenCount, pois editamos o mesmo para retornar 1 no lugar de 0
        if (!(i>chieldNames.length-1)) {
            txtv.setText(chieldNames[i][i1]);
            txtv.setPadding(100, 0, 0, 0);
            txtv.setTextSize(30);
        }else{

            //layout.chield_empty é só um linearlayout simples com um único textview dentro
            // escrito "chield vazio!!"
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.chield_empty, null);

            //Infla e retorna o mesmo
            return convertView;
        }
        return txtv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Desculpe amigo mas eu já tentei isso também... O grande problema que estou enfrentando é que quando não há filhos (childs) o meu "layout_personalizado_empty" não infla.

Comment: Dentro deste meu layout personalizado já existe um Textview personalizado com a mensagem = "Nada cadastrado para o usuário". Então para mim não é necessário fazer isto dinamicamente com setText()

Comment: O que é mais estranho para mim é que não infla de jeito nenhum. O layout com a mensagem de empty

Comment: @Andréalas entendi, mais a noite vou criar um teste para tentar reproduzir isso que está tentando fazer e te falo, pois eu nunca criei um layout só pra isso, eu geralmente retorno só um textview mesmo.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo. Espero que você consiga me ajudar... vou ficar no seu aguardo....

Comment: Amigo se você puder dá um "UP" na questão por favor para mim ganhar um pouco de reputação vou agradecer muito pois gastei muito nesta pergunta. Considere também que esta questão pode não ser somente um problema para mim e outros também possam ter no futuro. Também perceba que não tem nenhuma questão parecida no StackOverFlow em português....

Comment: @Andréalas opa, beleza!!

Comment: @ Murilo Portugal Oi campeão conseguiu fazer fazer o projeto? Se você puder, me mandar o código funcionando..... Você pode fazer uma lista simples mesmo e me mandar. Daí eu comparo os código e vejo o que fiz de errado..... Se fizer isso pra mim eu te passo a recompensa.... vlw abraços

Comment: @Andréalas, consegui sim, vou editar a resposta e colocar o código!

Comment: Ótimo meu amigo vou ficar no aguardo...

Comment: @Andréalas, já postei o código e comentei pra ficar melhor para você entender

Comment: Ótimo meu amigo... vou verificar o código aqui. Mas por ter se interessado em me ajudar, vou te dar a recompensa..... Obrigado e bom trabalho. Vou introduzir a sua resposta em meu app e provavelmente amanhã te dou uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @Andréalas, e precisando é só chamar!